# When to create an organization in hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

`Hyperledger` enables you to create participants (via chaincode) as well as Organisations (via fabric setup). In a supply chain or any process, how do you decide which one is an Organisation and which one is a participant.
From my understanding, all participants of same category should fall under one organisation.

But then I have another issue, will buyers also gonna have their own organizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Organizations on Hyperledger works like a Board of Directors, they vote in consensus inside your network, if you are the only one org then everything is auto approved by you, Ex. An upgrade in chaincode with new model.

**Use case:** Think about if we build a blockchain network for Banks, every institution will be an org and the participants are their respective clients.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on security and privacy factors.
let consider Maersk, If the network is setup within Maersk what's the purpose of hiding data within themselves ? untill and unless there is no trust within.
So if **Data Availabilty > Data privacy**, i'd go on creating Maersk as one **Organization** and all sub entity under them are **Peers** and one channel so that they can share data within and between them.
Now, what if someone other than Maersk entity needs to be involved? like fleet, shipping, delivery, Manufacturer etc, they are the separate Orgs as these Organizations don't need to share every data flowing in and out, they only require what they want to serve for Maersk.

There might be a case where each entity works separate and has their own rules and interaction with multiple other parties under a main entity. Then again you need to decide based on the data sharing ,Transparency, Availability between parties. if data is just available between one or two entity where does DLT concept comes in ? and how/where does consensus fit in ?!!

You need to keep all these factors over use case and decide upon creation of Org and Peer.

Correct me if i'm wrong